# Map a function on every two elements of a list

Tags: clojure, map-function

I need a function that maps a function only on every other element, e.g.

```
(f inc '(1 2 3 4)) 
=> '(2 2 4 4)
```

I came up with:

```
(defn flipflop [f l]
  (loop [k l, b true, r '()]
    (if (empty? k)
      (reverse r)
      (recur (rest k) 
             (not b) 
             (conj r (if b 
                       (f (first k)) 
                       (first k)))))))
```

Is there a prettier way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
(map #(% %2) 
     (cycle [f identity])
     coll)
```

Comment: so much better than my option (which I leave for comparison and edification purposes)

Comment: pretty neat indeed :), but your option is interesting as well.

Answer (score 2):

also, since you want to apply the function to some specific indiced items in the collection (even indices in this case) you could use `map-indexed`, like this:

```
(defn flipflop [f coll]
  (map-indexed #(if (even? %1) (f %2) %2) coll))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a good idea to look at Clojure's higher level functions before using loop and recur.

```
user=> (defn flipflop
         [f coll]
         (mapcat #(apply (fn ([a b] [(f a) b])
                             ([a] [(f a)]))
                         %)
                 (partition-all 2 coll)))
#'user/flipflop

user=> (flipflop inc [1 2 3 4])
(2 2 4 4)

user=> (flipflop inc [1 2 3 4 5])
(2 2 4 4 6)

user=> (take 11 (flipflop inc (range))) ; demonstrating laziness
(1 1 3 3 5 5 7 7 9 9 11)
```

this flipflop doesn't need to reverse the output, it is lazy, and I find it much easier to read.

The function uses `partition-all` to split the list into pairs of two items, and mapcat to join a series of two element sequences from the calls back into a single sequence.

The function uses apply, plus multiple arities, in order to handle the case where the final element of the partitioned collection is a singleton (the input was odd in length).

Answer (score 1):

Whereas [amalloy's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36105948/1562315) is *the one*, you could simplify your `loop` - `recur` solution a bit:

```
(defn flipflop [f l]
  (loop [k l, b true, r []]
    (if (empty? k)
      r
      (recur (rest k) 
             (not b) 
             (conj r ((if b f identity) (first k)))))))
```

This uses couple of common tricks:

- If an accumulated list comes out in the wrong order, use a vector
  instead.
- Where possible, factor out common elements in a conditional.